# Listing taxonomies from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type with several taxonomies within it

Eg. the post type is called `campsites` and the taxonomies are various `counties`: cheshire, staffordshire etc.

What I want to do is: list all of the counties and when you click on a county it links through to a page which lists all of the posts within that County. How can I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of functions for grabbing the data you need, a quick look at the Codex function reference reveals many useful functions you can use to build this.

Use [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) to get the link to that terms archive, and [`wp_get_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) to get the terms of an object/post.

To get all terms in a taxonomy use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

You'll find examples on each function page, e.g. displaying all terms in a taxonomy and linking to them:

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'my_term' );

$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);

$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $cape_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="/term-base/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; '; else $term_list .= '</p>';
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Though that example could be improved greatly by replacing the hyperlink code with code that uses `get_term_link`.

There are other useful functions such as `wp_list_categories` but that function is not as flexible and limits you to a dropdown box or list rather than whatever arbitrary markup you'd prefer